# Google App Script to Append Value from one Cell to String of Numbers in another Cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I’ve been trying to figure out how to write a script which will take the value from one cell and append it to the end of a string of numbers in another cell of that same row. The newly appended number needs to be separated by a comma from the previously appended value, and the whole string needs to be wrapped between brackets. EX. [2,3,3,4.5,2.5,2.1,1.3,0.4]. The script will need to loop through all of the rows containing data on a named sheet beginning with the third row.

[image]

The above image is obviously just an example containing only two rows of data. The actual spreadsheet will contain well over a thousand rows, so the operation must be done programmatically and will run weekly using a timed trigger.

To be as specific as I can, what I need help with is to first know if something like the appending is even possible in Google App Scripts. I've spent hours searching and I can't seem to find a way to append a new value (ex. cell A3) to the current string (ex. cell B3) without overwriting it completely. 
In full disclosure; I'm a middle school teacher trying to put something together for my school.

Comment: "Any help..." is a too broad question. Please edit it to make it specific. Ref [ask].

Comment: @Rubén I apologize for the poor question and thank you for your response. I've since attempted to clarify what I need help with.

Comment: AFAIK question saying something like "I'm willing to pay..." are not well received on this site.

Comment: Start writing a script and post the code you have so far. If you haven't, start researching `onEdit(e)`,`e.value`,`range.setValue()`,`range.getValue()`

Comment: C3: `=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(B3:B4,"\b]",","&A3:A4&"]"))` Note that if A you update A,Then previous values are not stored. The same is true of any custom function. That's why I suggested that you use onEdit(e) trigger.

Comment: @I'-'I Thanks again for your help. I went a different route but you've been very helpful in me finding my way to a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To be as specific as I can, what I need help with is to first know if something like the appending is even possible in Google App Scripts.

Seeing the expected result, it's inserting rather than appending, as the string should be added before the last character (`]`). Anyway, **yes, this is possible** by using JavaScript string handling methods.

- Use `getValue()` to the get the cell values, both the Current GPA and the GPA History.
- One way is to use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace)

Example using pure JavaScript:

```js
var currentGPA = 3.5
var gpaHistory = '[2,3.1,2.4]';
gpaHistory = gpaHistory.replace(']',','+currentGPA+']');
console.info(gpaHistory)
```

Once you get the modified `gpaHistory`, use `setValue(gpaHistory)` to add this value to the spreadsheet.