# Avoiding a TypeError object when Using the Map Method in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

Based on some [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235944/google-app-script-to-append-value-from-one-cell-to-string-of-numbers-in-another) I received yesterday, I've created a `@customFunction` script to run in my spreadsheet which "appends" a value to a string.

In column A of the spreadsheet I have a student's current GPA (ex. 3.2) and in column B I have a string of their previously recorded GPAs (ex. [2,3,3,4.5,2.5,2.1,1.3,0.4]). The script adds the current GPA to the end of the string.

In this case ***current*** and ***stored*** are named ranges in the spreadsheet.

```
/** @customFunction */
function GPAweekly(current,stored) {
stored = stored.replace(']',','+current+']');
return stored;
}
```

This works fine when using a 1D range and for only a few rows. However when I use it for larger amounts of data, I hit the Google's service quota and get the “Service invoked too many times in a short time” error.

My next attempt was to use a 2D range and the `map()` method to call my function recursively.

```
/** @customFunction */
function GPAweekly(current,stored) {
if (typeof current.map === "function" && typeof stored.map === "function") { 
return current.map(GPAweekly);
return stored.map(GPAweekly);
}  

stored = stored.replace(']',','+current+']');
return stored;
}
```

This seems to work until the script reaches the `replace()` method and then I get an error in the spreadsheet cell stating "TypeError: Cannot find function replace in object 0".

**I have two questions:**

**1)** How can I get around this TypeError issue?

**2)** Is there a more elegant way of handling what I'm trying to achieve overall (keep in mind I'll have a couple thousand students data to deal with).

I apologize for the title. I couldn't quite figure out how to word it.

Comment: Where exactly are you using this?  Which cell? Script was suggested because, you needed to directly edit/append values. If you were gonna use it as a custom function, it's much easier to do this with inbuilt functions.

Comment: @|'-'| Thanks for you explanations. I went ahead and used some of Gsheets native functions. Guess I was trying to make this more difficult than it needed to be. I'm having fun learning though!

Comment: If I may ask, What did you end up using?

Comment: I used three columns. In column 1 I have the new value to be appended, column 2 contains the previous value (string of numbers) to append to, and column 3 contains a script to containtinate the data from col 1 and 2. Something like this... `=IF(AND(TRIM($F3)="",TRIM($J3)=""),"",IF(AND(TRIM($F3)<>"",TRIM($J3)=""),CONCATENATE("[",$F3,"]"),IF(AND(TRIM($F3)="",TRIM($J3)<>""),$J3,(CONCATENATE(LEFT($J3,LEN($J3)-1),",",$F3,"]")))))` Easy enough. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) provides 3 parameters: the element, the index, and the original `Array`. Thus when you call `return current.map(GPAweekly);`, you are doing the equivalent of this code:

```
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  results.push(GPAweekly(arr[i], i, arr));
return results;
```

In other words, because the 2nd parameter given to `GPAweekly` is a number (`0`), rather than the presumed string, you receive the given error message. Also note that a multiple-range input is passed as a 2D array, even for a single column, e.g.

```
=GPAweekly(A1:A5, B1:B5) ->
/**
  current == [ [A1val], [A2val], [A3val], [A4val], [A5val] ]
  stored  == [ [B1val], [B2val], ... ]
 */
```

The solution is to ensure you call `GPAweekly` with both of the original parameters, and to extract the value from the inner array:

```
function GPAweekly(current, stored) {
  if (current.map && stored.map // Array test
      && current.length // Non-falsy length
      && current.length === stored.length // inputs are equally long
  ) {
    return current.map(function (row, i) {
      GPAweekly(row[0], stored[i][0]);
    });
  } else {
    // at least one of the tested conditions failed, so handle appropriately...
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explaining how the maps method works. Still trying to wrap my head around this.